# Error creating a group by in linq as it tells me that my name is not found in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, api, linq, .net-core

Currently I have a method where I try to create a query with a join where I join two tables, one for files and the other for products, based on that I get the files of my registered products, but I want to make a group by so that it only brings me the files grouped by my id and that way only show a single image and not all since when the detail is shown there if there will not be a single image but several.

```
// GET: api/<Producto>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetProd")]
    public IEnumerable<prodretorno> GetProd()
    {

   

        List<prodretorno> productos = (from prod in myDbContext.producto
                                       join arch in myDbContext.archivo on prod.idProducto equals arch.idProducto
                                      group prod by new 
                                       {    

                                           idProducto = prod.idProducto
                                       }
        into g
                                      select new prodretorno
                                      {
                                                                                       nombre = prod.nombre, //marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              descripcion = prod.descripcion, //marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              codigo = prod.codigo, //marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              inventario = prod.inventario,//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              precioPiso = prod.precioPiso,//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              precioProv = prod.precioProv,//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              precioPublico = prod.precioPublico,//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              fecha = prod.fecha,//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              Estatus = prod.Estatus,//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              idProducto = prod.idProducto,//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                              url = arch.url//marca error aqui en donde dice "prod"
                                      }).ToList();

     

        return productos;
       
    }
```

The error is as follows "the name prod does not exist in the current context". I already tried it in many ways but what I want is simple to group based on the id and return all the rows grouped together with all their necessary columns but based on the grouping.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to select object level properties after you group, but I have no idea what your models, database schema, or database data look like, nor the intention of your query (and what the group by is supposed to accomplish).

Comment: @gunr2171 Ok, I am trying to return from the query a response or result where I can use all attributes from my model but I need generate a group by with a id product

Comment: That Controller will be an absolute nightmare to manage in the future, you would be better off creating an abstraction that will call your data context- Also if you use SQL to a POCO you would save yourself the agony.